# React and rendering large portions of data

Tags: reactjs

I am building a component that displays news' from a certain category. Some pages may contain 100 articles, some 100 times more.

My current approach is to download a portion of 50 articles and render it inside a `<NewsListPortion>` simple (stateless, containing only `render`) component. But as those portions keep stacking, I re-render those already loaded. And isn't that a performance hit?

My code looks following:

```
  render() {
    if(this.state.loaded) {
      return (
        <div className="news-list__wrapper">
          {this.data.map(p => {
            const key = `${p.page}-${p.offset}`;
            if (p.data.length > 0) {
              return (
                <NewsListPortion key={key} page={p.page} offset={p.offset} data={p.data} />
              )
            }
          })}
          {this.state.progress ?
            <img src={loader} alt="" />
            :
            this.state.finished ?
              <div><hr />koniec</div>
              :
              <button id="load-more-news" onClick={this.loadNews.bind(this)}>Wczytaj więcej</button>
          }
        </div>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <img src={loader} alt="" />
      )
    }
  }
```

`this.data` is an array consisting of objects, like this:

```
[
  {
    page: 1,
    offset: 1,
    data: [{ // 50 articles }]
  },
  {
    page: 2,
    offset: 1,
    data: [{ // 50 articles }]
  }
]
```

So, again, my concern here is performance - re-rendering everything every time a new portfion arrives seems like a bad idea, but I have no idea how to do this any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React is not rerendeing everything when you are just supplying more newsportions. You have already attached a key to your news portion component , whenever new data(newssportion) comes, react will use all the previous keys and only add the appropriate newsportion and react wont touch the oldones.
Its all taken care by react , you dont have to anything extra for performance.

Just make your key is unique .